# Printing out a Histogram C++

Tags: c++, histogram

I am attempting to print out a histogram of values that correspond to the amount of times a pixel value appears in a .pgm file.  I know I am reading in the values correctly, it's when I try to print them where I have issues.

```
int pixelHold[product];

    for(long int i = 0; i < product; i++)
    {
        pixelHold[pixels[i]]++;
        //cout << pixels[i] << ' ' << endl;

    }
    for(long int j = 0; j < product; j++)
    {
        cout << pixelHold[j] << ' ';

    }
```

"product" is the Width x Height pixel value, which corresponds to the size of the vector I'm using to store all of the values.  "pixelHold" is just an array that I'm using to increment every time it comes across a pixel value.  For example, it if came across "222" 3 times, it would print a "3" for the "222" slot.

However, the issue is that, when I print the histogram, I get a bunch of zeroes, and then garbage for the last 100 slots or so.  When I change the parameters of the for loop to a smaller number, like "221", it prints out the correct histogram up to that point.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need to initalize your arrays - otherwise they contain absolutely arbitrary contents - the contents of RAM where the compiler decided to put your array.

Also, your histogram table should have the dimensions of 256 - since that's how many (8-bit) colors there are in a greyscale image.

The following code should do the trick:

```
const int histogramLevels = 256;
int pixelHold[histogramLevels];

for (int i=0; i<histogramLevels; i++) pixelHold[i] = 0;

for(long int i = 0; i < product; i++)
{
    pixelHold[pixels[i]]++;
    //cout << pixels[i] << ' ' << endl;

}

for (int i=0; i<histogramLevels; i++) {
    cout << pixelHold[j] << ' ';
}
```

Comment: You know, it's strange.  This helped me figure out why it wasn't working, but not for that reason! Haha! My second loop should only be printing out enough for the maximum pixel value in the array of values, not the entire product!  Thank you very much!  That's exactly what I was missing.

Comment: Btw, you could do "int pixelHold[product] = {0}". That's a convenient C/C++ trick will set each member of the array to its default value (0). It's common to see that done when initializing structs.

Comment: well, in practice, you should be printing out enough for the maximum *possible* value of the pixel in the array of values - otherwise you end up with graphs that are hard to compare since they are of different lengths.

Comment: I actually tried that.  But I kept getting an initialization error from the compiler.  *Shrug*

@qdot Yeah. The maximum pixel value is held in a variable I created, and is pulled from the .pgm file itself.  So that's what I'm using now for printing my histogram.

Comment: yeah, the ={0} trick is neat - when learning, however, clarity often trumps nice tricks (they get really hairy when initalizing large, complex structures)